# Что нужно добавить в код?

Tags: c

У меня есть программа, которая переводит ВСЕ буквы верхнего регистра в нижний. Что нужно добавить в неё или изменить, что бы только гласные буквы переходили в нижний регистр.

Код программы:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <locale.h>

void fun(char str1[]){
    int j;
    char ch1;
    printf("Введите предложение:\n");
    gets(str1);
    printf("\n");
    printf("\n");
    printf("Преобразование заглавных букв в прописныее имеет вид:\n");
    while (str1[j]) { 
        ch1 = str1[j];
        putchar(tolower(ch1)); 
        j++; 
    }

    } 

int main()
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL,"rus");
    int k = 0; 
    char ch2[] = "A E I O U Y \n"; 
    fun(ch2);
    return 0; 
}
```

Comment: как бы странно не звучало, но добавить нужно условие перед преобразованием символа =)

Comment: Использовать регулярное выражение `[аеёиоуыэюя]` или просто сравнение с каждой)

Comment: Добавьте `if (strchr("AEIOUY", ch1))` в программу

Answer (score 0):

я бы сделал так. но это для английского текста.

```
#include <stdio.h>

void to_lower ( char *str ) {
        do {
                *str += *str >= 'A' && *str <= 'Z' ? 32 : 0;
        } while ( *str++ );
}

int main ( ) {
        char test_str[] = "ALPHA most";

        to_lower ( test_str );

        printf ( "%s\n", test_str );
}
```

Comment: Но ведь эта программа тоже работает со всеми буквами верхнего регистра, а нужно только с гласными.

Comment: @Санёчек тогда добавить в массив гласные буквы и проходить по массиву, в поисках гласной буквы.